# Equivalent of "window["functionName"](arguments)" in server-side

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the equivalent code of `window["functionName"](arguments)` in NodeJS server-side?

Comment: @infact can you tell what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you're looking for `global`

Note, however, that in modules nothing is ever exposed to this level

Comment: `global[ 'functionName' ]( ... )` will work if the function is at the global level.  But as I said, modules don't expose anything to that level, they're all wrapped in an anonymous scope.

Comment: @MarkKahn, so how to call them?

Answer (score 128):

If you need such a capability within a module, one hack is to store such module functions in variables within the module and then call them by accessing them from the module object properties. Example:

```
var x = { }; // better would be to have module create an object
x.f1 = function()
{
    console.log('Call me as a string!');
}
```

Now, within the module, you can call it using the value from a string:

```
var funcstr = "f1";
x[funcstr]();
```

I am learning the ropes with Node myself, the above is probably all sorts of wrong :-). Perhaps a marginally better way to write this example would be (for the module m.js):

```
module.exports =
{
    f1: function() { console.log("Call me from a string!"); },
    f2: function(str1) { this[str1](); }
}
```

Now you can:

```
var m = require('m.js');
m.f2('f1');
```

Or even just:

```
var m = require('m.js');
m['f1']();
```

FWIW!

Comment: This is a more sustainable, maintainable, and normalized OO approach for JS. Thx.

Comment: Thanks I had to use something like this in some hard to abstract code today.

Comment: Excellent, i just needed x[funcstr](); because the method was added by some other plugin.

Answer (score 13):

### 1) If methods are in same js file

define all methods as properties of Handler:

```
var Handler={};

Handler.application_run = function (name) {
console.log(name)
}
```

Now call it like this

```
var somefunc = "application_run";
Handler[somefunc]('jerry codes');
```

**Output:** jerry codes

---

### 2) If you want to keep methods in a different js file

```
//    Handler.js
module.exports={
    application_run: function (name) {
        console.log(name)
    }
}
```

Use method defined in `Handler.js` in `different.js`:

```
//    different.js
var methods = require('./Handler.js')   // path to Handler.js
methods['application_run']('jerry codes')
```

**Output:** jerry codes

Answer (score 5):

If You need it in module scope, You can use something like this

```
var module = require('moduleName');

module['functionName'](arguments);
```

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, looking at all these answers they seem a bit too much work. I was playing around to look for other ways around this. You can use the `eval()` command to print a variable as text then call it as a function

I.e

```
let commands = ['add', 'remove', 'test'];
for (i in commands) {
    if (commands[i] == command) {
        var c = "proxy_"+command;
        eval(c)(proxy);
    }
}
```

`eval(string)(arg1, arg2);`

This example script would execute the function `proxy_test(proxy)`

Comment: elegant solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to call a class level function using `this` then following is the solution and it worked for me

```
class Hello {
  sayHello(name) {
    console.log("Hello " + name)
  }
  callVariableMethod() {
    let method_name = 'sayHello'
    this[`${method_name}`]("Zeal Nagar!")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You know, the OP's code inspired me to try this:

```
global.test = function(inVal){
    console.log(inVal);
}

global['test']('3 is the value')
```

But now that I think about it, it's no better than @Ravi' s answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for node, see if this approach works for you

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var fnA1 = require('functions/fnA1');
var fnA2 = require('functions/fnA2');

module.exports = {
    run: function(fnName, options, callback) { 
        'use strict';
        var nameSpace = fnName.toString().split('.');
        // if function name contains namespace, resolve that first before calling
        if (nameSpace.length > 1) {
            var resolvedFnName = this;
            _.forEach(nameSpace, function(name){
                resolvedFnName = resolvedFnName[name];
            });
            resolvedFnName(options, callback);
        } else {
            this[fnName](options, callback);
        }
    },
    fnA1: fnA1,
    fnA2: fnA2
};
```

call this like

```
importVariable.run('fnA1.subfunction', data, function(err, result){
    if (err) {return callback(err);}
    return callback(null, result);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

That is not specific to the window object. In JavaScript any property of the object can be accessed this way. For example,

```
var test = {
    prop1 : true
};

console.log(test.prop1); // true
console.log(test["prop1"]); // also true
```

Read more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Yes indeed. However I am looking for a way to calling functions by name specifically.